# Android Pie: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) android::Theme::ApplyStyle(unsigned int, bool)

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I am receiving the crash mentioned in the title in my play console

**It present only on Android Pie and limited to Pixel XL (marlin) and Pixel (sailfish) devices**

I have no idea what is causing it as I don't have anyway to reproduce this issue.

```
Here is the stack trace

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> sample.package.name <<<

backtrace:

  #00  pc 0000000000026bcc  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::Theme::ApplyStyle(unsigned int, bool)+472)

  #01  pc 000000000012c080  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeThemeApplyStyle(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, int, unsigned char)+92)

  #02  pc 00000000003d16d0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeThemeApplyStyle [DEDUPED]+176)

  #03  pc 00000000007bd0a4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.AssetManager.applyStyleToTheme+116)

  #04  pc 00000000007c6918  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.rebase+232)

  #05  pc 00000000007cc3a4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.newThemeImpl+228)

  #06  pc 00000000007c5fcc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.Resources.setImpl+412)

  #07  pc 00000000007733ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ResourcesManager.updateResourcesForActivity+1916)

  #08  pc 000000000087a780  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.performActivityConfigurationChanged+912)

  #09  pc 000000000087ac2c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChangedForActivity+220)

  #10  pc 000000000087f9fc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged+444)

  #11  pc 0000000000a75450  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.ActivityConfigurationChangeItem.execute+128)

  #12  pc 000000000077b7f4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks+708)

  #13  pc 000000000077b4b8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+280)

  #14  pc 000000000086d9f4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+308)

  #15  pc 0000000000aaa594  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+180)

  #16  pc 0000000000aad690  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1264)

  #17  pc 000000000087a358  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+664)

  #18  pc 000000000056064c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)

  #19  pc 00000000000cf6d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)

  #20  pc 00000000004661e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)

  #21  pc 0000000000467d38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)

  #22  pc 00000000003f6728  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)

  #23  pc 000000000011e6d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)

  #24  pc 0000000000be3a78  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)

  #25  pc 0000000000beac60  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3088)

  #26  pc 000000000056064c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)

  #27  pc 00000000000cf6d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)

  #28  pc 00000000004661e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)

  #29  pc 0000000000465de8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+424)

  #30  pc 0000000000368494  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+652)

  #31  pc 00000000000b1cb4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+136)

  #32  pc 00000000000b4640  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+752)

  #33  pc 000000000000219c  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1200)

  #34  pc 00000000000b05d8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
```

Any pointers as to what might be causing this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like one of the crash log from native library, basically one of the library is not supported by device architecture.

Comment: have create custom them style for app?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier It doesn't crash on Pie emulator

Comment: @MayurDabhi Yes

Comment: i think there it some attribute which not support that particular device, that why crash occur

Comment: @q126y Do you have any sample code?

Comment: @Kousic No. I don't know which code is causing the crash, so I can't provide sample code.

Comment: @q126y Ok, any more specific information about your issue?

Comment: @Kousic I have provided all the information that I have. It present only on Android Pie and limited to Pixel XL (marlin) and Pixel (sailfish) devices

Comment: @q126y Atleast, provide some steps you followed before receiving this error which could help us to identify your exact problem.

Comment: crashing in this code, but i can't find any specific reason.
http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/AssetManager2.cpp#904

Comment: Is it possible to share `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Do you have libandroidfw.so file in your project and yes then for which arch you have like lib64 lib32

Comment: @aminography Company policy would prevent me from doing so. If you can think of something in `build.gradle` file that may cause this issue, do let me know, I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, what is your `compileSdkVersion`? Is it 28?

Comment: @aminography
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

Comment: By any chance did you find a solution? I am really struggling with something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293193/a-libc-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-fault-addr-0x740078008d

Answer (score 0):

What I can point out from here is that you're using a custom theme that is not supported on a real device. Happens to me so many time that the bug doesn't happen on the emulator but on actual device. I suggest to test the build with a real device (with latest android , as well as the previous two or three versions), before moving to production.

Answer (score 0):

this is coming from `AppCompatActivity.setTheme()`.

the native stack-trace without the least code makes it difficult to determine if this is caused by either:

- `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`
- `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

migrating to `androidx.appcompat` might be an option - or migrating back to `android.support.v7`.

also, trying another theme might be worth a try - or simply not setting the theme on marlin & sailfish.

Comment: I have migrated to androidx, and the issue is still present. I am setting theme attributes in `try catch(throwable t)` block, it should not cause the crash.