# Android signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android

I cannot make sense of the below log. This crash is completely random and I cannot reproduce it when I want.

It goes after closing the application a few times and randomly appears again. I do not see any null reference in the backtrace and also do not know how can I approach to root cause this issue.

```
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000761fda6341  x2  fffffffffffffff1  x3  626173652e61706b
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x4  6b70612e65736162  x5  626173652e61706b  x6  6b70612e65736162  x7  b40000761fd9d850
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000007fdf9e0f80  x9  0000000000000051  x10 000000761fda6310  x11 0000000000000028
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x12 b40000761fd9dfd0  x13 b40000761fd9ce90  x14 b4000076bfd99ea0  x15 0000000000000000
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000078c37f74b0  x17 00000078c314da00  x18 00000078c7392000  x19 0000000000000000
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000000000000008  x22 0000000000000008  x23 000000761fd996b9
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000007fdf9e0f80  x25 000000761fd996b0  x26 0000000000000041  x27 000000762fd9d970
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007fdf9e0f80  x29 0000007fdf9e1090
2021-11-10 23:03:31.481 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:     lr  00000078c37c685c  sp  0000007fdf9e0f30  pc  00000078c37c6874  pst 0000000060001000

2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000003f874  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::Theme::SetTo(android::Theme const&)+748) (BuildId: 86183bd0cc7cbac63afac4d9bf006c31)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000001298b8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeThemeCopy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, long, long)+132) (BuildId: 283a5983e366baeaf0804046adc1a46b)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000237ed0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+176) (BuildId: 38cc5e4749932978b37153c2fa7e7745be380943)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00000000001347e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0000000000198eb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 000000000030c254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000003083dc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 0000000000641070  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+412) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000000000012ec94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static_range+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000003f64ec  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.AssetManager.setThemeTo+28)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 000000000063ea10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+1204) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 000000000012eb14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 00000000003fdf7c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.setTo+28)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 00000000003fd58c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.Resources$Theme.setTo+8)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 00000000002dd576  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1310000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+62)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 000000000063d838  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1164) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00000000002dd5dc  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1310000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme+12)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.631 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 000000000024d4aa  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1bf3000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor+102)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 000000000024e1da  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1bf3000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor+22)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 000000000063d838  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1164) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 000000000024b954  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1bf3000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView+16)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 0000000000198f12  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~05JIECyXxSxDEaauNMKBIw==/com.dhavalpateln.linkcast-mqdtrEyakjtGvVjBLUZtew==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor+170)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 000000000063d838  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1164) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 000000000019ad84  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~05JIECyXxSxDEaauNMKBIw==/com.dhavalpateln.linkcast-mqdtrEyakjtGvVjBLUZtew==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor+8)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 000000000063d838  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1164) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #38 pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #39 pc 000000000019b668  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~05JIECyXxSxDEaauNMKBIw==/com.dhavalpateln.linkcast-mqdtrEyakjtGvVjBLUZtew==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #41 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #42 pc 0000000000197834  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~05JIECyXxSxDEaauNMKBIw==/com.dhavalpateln.linkcast-mqdtrEyakjtGvVjBLUZtew==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView+8)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #43 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #44 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #45 pc 0000000000005010  [anon:dalvik-classes7.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~05JIECyXxSxDEaauNMKBIw==/com.dhavalpateln.linkcast-mqdtrEyakjtGvVjBLUZtew==/base.apk!classes7.dex] (com.dhavalpateln.linkcast.AnimeAdvancedView.onCreate+12)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #46 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #47 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #48 pc 00000000001d47d0  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.performCreate+88)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #49 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #50 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #51 pc 00000000001d475e  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.performCreate+2)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #52 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #53 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #54 pc 00000000002507a6  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate+6)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #55 pc 00000000002fed48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+268) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #56 pc 0000000000306a10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #57 pc 0000000000307cf0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1780) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #58 pc 000000000016d13c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+45276) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #59 pc 00000000001407d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #60 pc 00000000001c0e3c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #61 pc 00000000002fee50  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+532) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #62 pc 0000000000306a10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #63 pc 0000000000307cf0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1780) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #64 pc 000000000016d13c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+45276) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #65 pc 00000000001407d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #66 pc 00000000001c0d28  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #67 pc 00000000002fee50  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+532) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #68 pc 0000000000306a10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #69 pc 0000000000307350  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+856) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #70 pc 000000000063b0d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+868) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #71 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #72 pc 00000000002e7dd2  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute+134)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #73 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #74 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #75 pc 00000000002ea216  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks+154)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #76 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #77 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #78 pc 00000000002ea152  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+146)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #79 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #80 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #81 pc 00000000001c00f4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+276)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #82 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #83 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #84 pc 000000000040d5b2  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x9ca000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #85 pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.632 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #86 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #87 pc 000000000044d0f4  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x9ca000) (android.os.Looper.loop+480)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #88 pc 00000000002fed48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+268) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #89 pc 0000000000306a10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #90 pc 0000000000307cf0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1780) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #91 pc 000000000016f3e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+54148) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #92 pc 00000000001407d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #93 pc 00000000001cbbbc  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #94 pc 00000000002fee50  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+532) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #95 pc 0000000000629a84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+796) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #96 pc 000000000013dff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #97 pc 00000000001347e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #98 pc 0000000000198eb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #99 pc 0000000000532198  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #100 pc 0000000000533e8c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1352) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #101 pc 00000000004b5438  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #102 pc 000000000008a614  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: 75c5df48e5d892592fa1a3a80192bd084017e504)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #103 pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #104 pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #105 pc 000000000030c254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #106 pc 000000000030736c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+884) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #107 pc 000000000063b0d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+868) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #108 pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #109 pc 000000000023443e  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1bf3000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #110 pc 00000000002fed48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13759017899667232327)+268) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #111 pc 0000000000629a84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+796) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #112 pc 000000000013dff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #113 pc 0000000000afe44c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2444) (BuildId: 38cc5e4749932978b37153c2fa7e7745be380943)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #114 pc 00000000001347e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #115 pc 0000000000198eb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #116 pc 0000000000532198  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #117 pc 0000000000531d90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+428) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #118 pc 0000000000532cf8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #119 pc 00000000004249f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: 81dad8c48b7ecb0d08b213ea289200a0)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #120 pc 000000000009d434  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 283a5983e366baeaf0804046adc1a46b)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #121 pc 00000000000a5640  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+848) (BuildId: 283a5983e366baeaf0804046adc1a46b)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #122 pc 000000000000358c  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1348) (BuildId: cb4a9b8a8482f0772689ddc73871203d)
2021-11-10 23:03:31.633 18164-18164/? A/DEBUG:       #123 pc 000000000004a1e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: ae5ca7b3d2e4ea0c2302dafb7c10ad87)
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881129/android-pie-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-androidthemeapplystyl

Comment: By any chance did you find a solution? I am really struggling with something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293193/a-libc-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-fault-addr-0x740078008d